# How do I toggle two images using jQuery and radio buttons?

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

This isn't pretty, but I think you'll get what I'm trying to do.

```
<label><input name="jpgSel" type="radio" value="0">jpg 1</label><br />
<label><input name="jpgSel" type="radio" value="1">jpg 2</label><br />
<div id="showjpg"></div>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function () {
           if ($("jpgSel:checked").val() == 1) {
            $('#showjpg').attr({
                src: 'one.jpg',
                 alt: 'one dot jpg'
        });
    }
    else {
            $('#showjpg').attr({
                 src: 'two.jpg',
                 alt: 'two dot jpg'
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues:

- The `#showjpg` element is a `div`, you should have there an `img` element.
- The selector you are using to bind the `change` event is incorrect (`$("select")`), it should be something like `$("input[name=jpgSel]")`
- If you bind the change event to both radio buttons, you can get the value of the selected element simply by `this.value`.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name=jpgSel]").change(function () {
    if (this.value == "0") {
      $('#showjpg').attr({
        src: 'one.jpg',
        alt: 'one dot jpg'
      });
    } else {
      $('#showjpg').attr({
        src: 'two.jpg',
        alt: 'two dot jpg'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Check an example [here](http://jsbin.com/axaze/4/).

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. And thoroughly explained. Seriously, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($("jpgSel:checked").val() == 1) {
```

should read

```
if ($("#jpgSel:checked").val() == 1) {
```

or was that a typo?

Also you may want to use `$('#jpgSel:checked')` on its own w/out `== 1`

**edit**

oh and `$("input[@name='jpgSel']").click(function(){` might be better.

Comment: You don't need the `@` anymore, nor the single quotes. So `$("input[name=jpgSel]")...` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

jpgSel is a name and has to be selected like this

```
$("[name='jpgSel']:checked")
```

although i think it would be easier to scrap that and use the .click() function like so

```
$("[name='jpgSel'][value='0']").click(function{/*do something*/});
$("[name='jpgSel'][value='1']").click(function{/*do something else*/});
```